# 100% area plot of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, plot

In [pandas' documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#area-plot) you can find a discussion on *area plots*, and in particular stacking them. Is there an easy and straightforward way to get a 100% area stack plot like this one

[image]

from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16899920/671013)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The method is basically the same as in [the other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16899920/671013); divide each row by the sum of the row:

```
df = df.divide(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

Then you can call `df.plot(kind='area', stacked=True, ...)` as usual.

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(2015)

y = np.random.randint(5, 50, (10,3))
x = np.arange(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(y, index=x)

df = df.divide(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
ax = df.plot(kind='area', stacked=True, title='100 % stacked area chart')

ax.set_ylabel('Percent (%)')
ax.margins(0, 0) # Set margins to avoid "whitespace"

plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Another possibility is `pandas.DataFrame.plot.area()`

Comment: `ax.margins(0, 0)` is fragile and frequently won't work as expected. `ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=True)` is better in modern matplotlib.