# 100% stacked area/histogram in matplotlib with dates on X axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, time, histogram

I would like to take the best of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672375/histogram-in-matplotlib-time-on-x-axis) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875546/create-a-100-stacked-area-chart-with-matplotlib) questions. Namely, I have a `DataFrame` that contains the test name, date of execution and outcome. And I want to showcase how the percentage of failed cases decreased over time.

My data looks like this:

```
TestName;Date;IsPassed
test1;12/8/2016 9:44:30 PM;0
test1;12/8/2016 9:39:00 PM;0
test1;12/8/2016 9:38:29 PM;1
test1;12/8/2016 9:38:27 PM;1
test2;12/8/2016 5:05:02 AM;1
test3;12/7/2016 8:58:36 PM;0
test3;12/7/2016 8:57:19 PM;1
test3;12/7/2016 8:56:15 PM;1
test4;12/5/2016 6:50:49 PM;0
test4;12/5/2016 6:49:50 PM;0
test4;12/5/2016 3:23:09 AM;1
test4;12/4/2016 11:51:29 PM;1
```

And I was using this code to plot the cases separately:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
passed = tests[tests.IsPassed == 1]
failed = tests[tests.IsPassed == 0]
passed_dates = mdates.date2num(passed.Date.astype(datetime))
failed_dates = mdates.date2num(failed.Date.astype(datetime))
ax.hist(passed_dates, bins=10, color='g')
ax.hist(failed_dates, bins=10, color='r')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d.%m.%y'))
plt.show()
```

But now I would like to

1. Divide the time span into a configurable amount of buckets
2. Count the amount of test runs per bucket (without for loops, as there is a lot of entries in the dataframe)
3. Plot either a 100% area chart or the stacked histogram per each bucket, so that the amount from step 2 is 100%

The problem for me right now is that the perfectly working solution with the `hist()` takes care of summing up automatically, and I don't see a way to pass the Y axis to it.

**Update**

Here is what I'd like to accomplish (taken from another source):
[image: 100% Stacked columns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the argument `stacked = True` allows you to provide several arrays as input to `plt.hist`.

```
ax.hist([passed_dates, failed_dates], bins=10, stacked=True, label=["passed", "failed"])
```

[image]

Using relative counts requires to divide by the number of absolute counts per bin. This functionality is not built into the `hist` function. You would need to calculate the histograms manually and then plot the result as stacked bar plots.

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range("2016/01/01","2016/06/01" )
dates2 = pd.date_range("2016/02/01","2016/03/17", freq="18H")
dates = dates.append(dates2)

passed = np.round(np.random.rand(len(dates))+0.231).astype(np.int8)
tests = pd.DataFrame({"Date" : dates, "IsPassed": passed})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
passed = tests[tests.IsPassed == 1]
failed = tests[tests.IsPassed == 0]
all_dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(tests.Date.astype(datetime.datetime))
passed_dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(passed.Date.astype(datetime.datetime))
failed_dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(failed.Date.astype(datetime.datetime))

hist, bins = np.histogram(all_dates, bins=10)
histpassed, bins_ = np.histogram(passed_dates, bins=bins)
histfailed, bins__ = np.histogram(failed_dates, bins=bins)

binwidth=bins[1]-bins[0]
ax.bar(bins[:-1]+binwidth/2., histpassed/hist, width=binwidth*0.8, label="passed")
ax.bar(bins[:-1]+binwidth/2., histfailed/hist, width=binwidth*0.8, bottom=histpassed/hist, label="failed")

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%d.%m.%y'))
ax.legend()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.savefig(__file__+".png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the hint. Now is there a way to switch from the absolute count on Y axis to percentage? Right now some bins sum up to over a thousand runs, while others are less than 100...

Comment: See edited answer. If this still does not help, feel free to ask further.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for!  Thanks, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest! There are a couple of things that would like to change to adapt to my needs, but those are off the topic of this question.